# I believe this is too much, covering ALL of my windows

Tags: criminal-law

These A4 notices where covering every window of my car, 3 on windscreen, 2 back widow, 1 one each other, i believe a simple don't park would suffice, this was over kill, can I do anything

[image: A4 NOTICES]

Comment: Take them off before you drive it

Comment: You could sue for criminal damage, if any actual damage is caused during the removal of those notices - however, that will cost you an initial outlay in solicitors fees and court costs and isn't guaranteed to have a successful outcome.  You could also just take this as a learnable event and not park in other peoples spots?  The owner of the parking spot may have the legal right to have your car removed at your expense, and/or issue you with a penalty charge if suitable notices have been posted, so you might consider yourself to have got off lightly here perhaps?

Comment: @Moo is right on all points. It would be a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

(Converting comment into an answer)

You could sue for criminal damage, if any actual damage is caused during the removal of those notices - however, that will cost you an initial outlay in solicitors fees and court costs and isn't guaranteed to have a successful outcome.

You could also just take this as a learnable event and not park in other peoples spots? The owner of the parking spot may have the legal right to have your car removed at your expense, and/or issue you with a penalty charge if suitable notices have been posted, so you might consider yourself to have got off lightly here perhaps?

Comment: I guess I should just let it go